# Java how to increment an int 1 every second until it gets to 15

Tags: java, android, time, int

I'd like to know how i can add 1 to my int every second until it reaches a certain number in this case 15.

But i would only want the int to start increasing once i have pressed a button.

```
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            login.addAction(Actions.moveTo(0, 310, 1));

            loginClicked = true;

            if(loginClicked == true && loginTimer == 15){
                login.addAction(Actions.moveTo(0, 430, 1));
            }
        }
    });
```

There is my code as you can see i am making something move then after 15 seconds if it remains untouched i want it too move back.

Comment: have a look at timer http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use a Timer:

```
int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
int period = 1000; // repeat every sec.
int count = 0;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
               // Your code

                count++;


            }
        }, delay, period);
```

Comment: Why doesn't that have problems? Should `count` be `final`?

Answer (score 4):

```
   Timer _t,timer;
   int _count=1;   
   TextView _tv
```

Initialize the timer

```
    _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );              

  _t = new Timer();
            _t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                _count++;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui threa
                 {
                  public void run() 
                  { 

                     if(_count<=15)
                     {
                      _tv.setText(""+_count);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                     _t.cancel();
                     }
                 }
                 });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000 );
```

You can use a timer as above. but i would suggest you use to use a handler

Using Handler

```
      TextView _tv ;
      Handler m_handler;//= new Handler();
      Runnable m_handlerTask ;
     _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
     m_handler = new Handler();
      m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
    {
         @Override 
         public void run() {
             if(_count<=15)
             {
              _tv.setText(""+_count);
              _count++;
             }
            else 
              {
                m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
              }
              m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);
         }
    };
    m_handlerTask.run();
```

Answer (score 2):

with an handler:

```
   Handler handler = new Handler();


    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (++counter < 15) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000L);
                    return;
                }

                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        }, 1000L);

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `Countdown Timer` just put at the `ontick` an element of `int = bob++;`

```
String convertbob = String.valueof(bob);
TextViewName.setText(convertbob);
```

and what ever you wanted to do at `onFinish`

I hope it would help others, its okay to cheat the real function of countdown just be wise.